# C++ program cannot find boost

Tags: c++, boost, evolutionary-algorithm, cc

I am trying to compile the MultiNEAT project (https://github.com/peter-ch/MultiNEAT). I have installed boost and boost-python, and it is located in /usr/local/Cellar/boost. I also edited ~/.bash_profile to add /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/include to PATH. However, when I try to compile and install MultiNEAT by

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I get the error:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_MultiNEAT' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/Genome.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.11-intel-2.7/src/Genome.o -march=native -DUSE_BOOST_PYTHON -DUSE_BOOST_RANDOM -std=gnu++11 -g -Wall
src/Genome.cpp:37:10: fatal error: 'boost/unordered_map.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
     ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I make the program found the boost library and successfully comiple MultiNEAT? My system is OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your compilation definitions to include the boost header files. You may, possibly, need to add the boost libraries (and their directories) to the linkage settings. I could have said more if you have published the way you build your application.

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for answering! I downloaded the code of MultiNEAT and try to build the application by running the python script it offered 'sudo python setup.py install', following the instruction on http://multineat.com/download.html. I am not quite familiar with stuffs like CMake or cc. All I know is that the system is build through the setup.py file.

Comment: What I see in the `setup.py` means that you have to manually edit it and add the locations of your BOOST header files and libraries to the relevant commands. There are `extra_compile_args=` and `libraries=` expressions for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, actually I tried that, such as add '-DBOOST_ROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/include/' in "extra_compile_args=" expressions, but still failed to compile.

Comment: You should add something like `-I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/include/` and `-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/lib`

Comment: Thanks so much! After adding the two arguments, it can find boost and compile now! Just curious why I have to offer such two arguments after I have added the paths to the PATH.

Comment: Because PATH has nothing to do with the compilation and linking. They do totally different things. You should study the compilation process if you are going to develop in C/C++. It is very useful knowledge.

Comment: Besides, the program shows error, which said 'ld: library not found for -lboost-python'. My boost-python is installed in /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.60.0/. So how can I add two paths using the -L argument?

Comment: I tried to add two -L for libaries and the output shows: `warning: no library file corresponding to '-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/lib' found (skipping)
warning: no library file corresponding to '-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.60.0/lib' found (skipping)`, but I have checked and I am sure the libraries are there.

Comment: Hi @Michael , I finally figured out! I added `library_dirs=['/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/lib',
                                            '/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.60.0/lib'],` in the `ext_modules=` , and `'-I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/include/'` in the `extra_compile_args=`, and now it compiles successfully!